# Connecting the Google Calendar API using PHP on a private server running on the LAN

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with the Google Calendar API connection. I have my own LAN server on which I have an invoice system. I thought that when issuing an invoice, information would be added to the calendar with the invoice number and when the company should pay it. I used Google cloud, but there was a problem because Google cloud needs a website and a publicly accessible one, and with such a small system it is not profitable. I tried using "new Google_Client()"
and as far as I know, the entries are added to the service account created in Google Cloud, but there is still a problem with displaying them in the calendar.
When adding a service account, it is not possible to enter a password, which makes it impossible to log in and transfer the calendar for another account. The calendar tries to display in the Administrator account.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('API_JSON');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Tekst',
    'description' => 'Tekst',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2023-12-01T09:00:00',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Warsaw',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2023-12-12T17:00:00',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Warsaw',
    ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary'; // 'primary' odnosi się do kalendarza głównego danego konta
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
?><pre><?php
print_r($event);
?></pre><?php
echo 'Wydarzenie zostało dodane: ' . $event->htmlLink ;
```

I know that the event is being added because it is possible to check it with this code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('API_JSON');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'primary'; // 'primary' odnosi się do kalendarza głównego danego konta
$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId);

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    echo '<br>------------------------<br>';
    echo 'ID: ' . $event->getId() . '<br>';
    echo 'Nazwa: ' . $event->getSummary() . '<br>';
    echo 'Opis: ' . $event->getDescription() . '<br>';
    echo 'Start: ' . $event->getStart()->getDateTime() . '<br>';
    echo 'Koniec: ' . $event->getEnd()->getDateTime() . '<br>';
    echo '------------------------<br>';
}
```

Comment: Googles service accounts do not have a traditional user interface, you can share the calendar with your primary Google account. In the Google Cloud Console, grant your primary account permission to view and edit the service account's calendar. Make sure that you're using the correct calendar ID. If you intend to use a specific calendar other than the primary one, replace 'primary' with the ID of that calendar.

Answer (score 0):

After a more thorough Google search and asking chatGPT, I found a solution using PHP code and shared the calendar with the main user. The code below may be useful to someone. I don't know if this is a good solution, if someone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it :D

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('API_JSON');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Identyfikator kalendarza, który chcesz udostępnić
$calendarId = 'primary'; // Możesz zmienić na identyfikator konkretnego kalendarza

// Adres e-mail, którego chcesz dodać jako współwłaściciela
$emailToAddAsOwner = 'TEST@TEST.com';

// Sprawdź, czy użytkownik już jest właścicielem
$isOwner = false;
$acl = $service->acl->listAcl($calendarId);
foreach ($acl->getItems() as $rule) {
    if ($rule->getRole() === 'owner' && $rule->getScope()->getValue() === $emailToAddAsOwner) {
        $isOwner = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Jeśli użytkownik nie jest jeszcze właścicielem, dodaj go
if (!$isOwner) {
    $rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
    $scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();
    $scope->setType('user');
    $scope->setValue($emailToAddAsOwner);
    $rule->setScope($scope);
    $rule->setRole('owner');

    $createdRule = $service->acl->insert($calendarId, $rule);

    echo 'Dodano współwłaściciela: ' . $createdRule->getScope()->getValue();
} else {
    echo 'Użytkownik jest już właścicielem kalendarza.';
}
```